# Pyspark - Update a data frame based on condition by comparing values in a different dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframe:

old_df - will be a fixed dataframe;
new_df - keeps changing every day.

For each Id, based on the values of age column in new_df, the age in old_df will be updated and counter is incremented by 1 whenever there is an update. If there is no change in age, then the counter and age columns remains in the same value (no increment)

old_df: (edit, included 5th ID)

```
id age counter
1   12   0
2   15   0
3   22   0
4   19   0
5   11   0
```

new_df

```
id  age 
1   20   
2   21   
3   22   
4   19
```

**Output** of old_df now should be:

old_df:

```
id age counter
1   20   1
2   21   1
3   22   0
4   19   0
5   11   0
```

Until Now I have tried the following:

```
df_old = df_old.withColumnRenamed('id','id_old')\
.withColumnRenamed('age','age_old')

joinedDF = df_old.join(df_new, df_new["id"] == df_old["id_old"], "outer")

if(joinedDF.select(joinedDF.age_old != joinedDF.age)):
        joinedDF = joinedDF.withColumn("age_old",joinedDF['age'])
        joinedDF = joinedDF.withColumn("counter",joinedDF['counter']+1)


joinedDF[['id_old', 'age_old', 'counter']].toPandas()


id_old age_old counter
1         20   1
2         21   1
3         22   1
4         19   1
```

If you could see the output that I got for id_old = 3 and 4, I should have achieved counter value as 0 but I get as 1.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This how you can achieve the same,

```
row = Row('id', 'age','counter')
old_df = spark.createDataFrame([row(1, 12, 0), row(2, 15, 0), row(3, 22, 0), row(4, 19, 0)])
old_df.show()

row2 = Row('id', 'age')
new_df = spark.createDataFrame([row(1, 20), row(2, 21), row(3, 22), row(4, 19)])
new_df.show()

old_df = old_df.alias("old_df").join(new_df.alias("new_df"), old_df.id == new_df.id, "inner").selectExpr("old_df.id as id", "new_df.age as age ",
                                                                          "if(old_df.age != new_df.age, old_df.counter+1,old_df.counter) as counter").sort("id")

old_df.show()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
+---+---+-------+
| id|age|counter|
+---+---+-------+
|  1| 12|      0|
|  2| 15|      0|
|  3| 22|      0|
|  4| 19|      0|
+---+---+-------+

+---+---+
| id|age|
+---+---+
|  1| 20|
|  2| 21|
|  3| 22|
|  4| 19|
+---+---+

+---+---+-------+
| id|age|counter|
+---+---+-------+
|  1| 20|      1|
|  2| 21|      1|
|  3| 22|      0|
|  4| 19|      0|
+---+---+-------+
```

Comment: If this is what you expecting please consider accepting the answer @user1994.